# Can Spring Security accept multiple passwords for the same user?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have Spring Security working within my application to authenticate a user with one password. I'm trying to meet a requirement that an override password will also authenticate that same user.

How can I do this with Spring Security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, you will have to implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` possibly by extending the existing `DaoAuthenticationProvider` (see `additionalAuthenticationChecks()` in there).
Also the user is only associated with a single password by default (`UserDetails.getPassword()`), so you will need to have an extension of that class holding multiple passwords, and a corresponding implementation of `UserDetailsService` that knows how to load the user along with its passwords.

Comment: I implemented my own AuthenticationProvider and performed the work I needed in the overridden authenticate() method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: any example on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to do by providing multiple 'AuthenticationProvider' with 'UserDetailsService'.

```
private DaoAuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);    
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return provider;
}

private DaoAuthenticationProvider superVisorAuthProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(supervisorDetailService);
    return provider;
}
```

then

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(userAuthProvider());
    auth.authenticationProvider(superVisorAuthProvider());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned - you can overwrite 'additionalAuthenticationChecks'
Hope this helps somebody.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
class FlexibleAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder

    @PostConstruct
    def init() {
        super.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        super.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(
            UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication)
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            log.error('Unable to authenticate with regular credentials')
           
            try {
                def mutableUserDetails = new MutableUser(userDetails)
                mutableUserDetails.password = 'alternatepassword'
                return super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(mutableUserDetails, authentication)
            } catch (AuthenticationException err) {
                log.error('Token based authentication failed')
            }
            
            throw e
        }
    }
    
    static class MutableUser implements UserDetails {

        private String password
        private final UserDetails delegate

        MutableUser(UserDetails user) {
            this.delegate = user
            this.password = user.password
        }

        String getPassword() {
            return password
        }

        void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password
        }

        ....

    }


}







@Configuration
class AuthWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    FlexibleAuthenticationProvider flexibleAuthenticationProvider

    ....

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(flexibleAuthenticationProvider)
    }

    ....

}
```